# Notifications list for Azure API Management using REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, azure-api-management

Anybody know if it's possible to add email addresses to the notification list for Azure API Mangement via a REST API?  Specifically, I would like to be able to add to the "Approaching subscription quota limit".  I see that there's a way to do this in the UI, but I'm looking for a way to do this via REST call or PowerShell commandlet (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are still in progress, and stuff might change a bit, but in short:

GET /notifications - get list of all notifications in system

GET /notifications/{nid} get single notification

GET /notifications/{nid}/recipients - get list of recipients for single notification

GET /notifications/{nid}/recipients/emails - get list of email recipients subscribed to notification

GET /notifications/{nid}/recipients/users- get list of user recipients subscribed to notification

GET/HEAD/PUT/DELETE /notifications/{nid}/recipients/emails/{email} - get/manage single email recipient

GET/HEAD/PUT/DELETE /notifications/{nid}/recipients/users/{user} - get/manage single user recipient

Answer (score 1):

I just got a response from Microsoft.  It turns out that it's only possible to add email addresses to the notification list by UI at the moment.