# Has REST API for adding to notification list in Azure API Management changed?

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, azure-api-management

This is related to the following stack overflow question:  [adding to notification list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524016/notifications-list-for-azure-api-management-using-rest-api)

The above suggestion worked for a time.  However, I am now getting an http 401 error when I call it.  Has it changed?  Here is the PowerShell code I'm using:

```
# Add emails
$emailArray = $QuotaLimitNotificationList -split ','
foreach($email in $emailArray)
{
    $email = $email.Trim()
    # Build the URL
    $resourcePath = $Nid + "/recipients/emails/" + $email + "?api-version=" + $apiVersion
    $url = "https://$urlHost/$resourcePath"
    $u
    # Make the REST call
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Header @{ "Authorization" = $apiKey; "Content-Type" = $contentType }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that $apiKey still contains valid not expired token?

Comment: Yes, positive.  I generated a new token which expires on the 25th of this month.  The error message I get is this:  "The remote server returned an error:  (404) Not Found...."

Comment: Here's the full uri I'm using:  {url host address}/notifications/QuotaLimitApproachingPublisherNotificationMessage/recipients/emails/{email to add}?api-version=2016-10-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Api was changed to confirm to Azure REST Guidelines. We are now going to document the entire set, and then it will not change. To unblock you here is the new paths

`GET /notifications/{nid}/recipientEmails` - get list of email recipients subscribed to notification
`GET /notifications/{nid}/recipientUsers` - get list of user recipients subscribed to notification

Comment: Great!  Thank you!